# It's possible to access $sheet in Import class of laravel-excel or get cell style from PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: laravel-excel, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

Imagine we are importing a excel, and using toCollection method.

And we need fill color of row or cell we using.

I can't figure how to access $sheet to get fill color or other properties of cell.

Anyway, i tried to use beforeImport event to access $currentWorkSheet of PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet to know what is color of cell

```
public static function beforeImport(BeforeImport $event)
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
            \Log::info(json_encode($event->getDelegate()->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A$i")->getValue()));
            \Log::info(json_encode($event->getDelegate()->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A$i")->getFill()->exportArray()));
        }
    }
```

But for a column like this

[image]

I get this log that showing fill color is empty at all...

```
"AAAA"
{"fillType":"none","rotation":0}
"a2"
{"fillType":"none","rotation":0}
"a3"
{"fillType":"none","rotation":0}
"a4"
{"fillType":"none","rotation":0}
"a5"
{"fillType":"none","rotation":0}
"a6"
{"fillType":"none","rotation":0}
"a7"
{"fillType":"none","rotation":0}
"a8"
{"fillType":"none","rotation":0}
"a9"
{"fillType":"none","rotation":0}
```

Can anyone give me some idea why PHPOffice can't read cell properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [Formatting cells](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells) section, you can export style as an array as follows:

```
$styleArray = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->exportArray();
```

Rather than

```
$styleArray = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->getFill()->exportArray();
```

You could give it a try, hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for answer, but if you look on log, i'm using $event->getDelegate()->getActiveSheet() to get current $sheet, and using ->getStyle("A$i")->getFill()->exportArray() , but all of them have same exportArray. i used without getFill() and still same, cause of long and not good readable, i filtered getFill() to it.

Comment: i passed file address to import class, then i created spreadsheet using PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet and able to get class, but using laravel-excel i can't get styles anyway..